# Applescript to Launch Chrome (with specifics)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, applescript

I'm really struggling with creating some method of launching a browser window (chrome) on osx with specifics such as window size, no tabs etc. Traditionally I've used vb script through windows with IE which is a pretty simple exercise but I'll be the first to admit, when it comes to macs I struggle greatly.

So here is my wish list.

I need to be able to open a window (ideally in chrome, but any other browser except safari), that has no status bar, no address bar with a given URL, and a specific window size. I did manage something in safari using do javaScript, and attempted the same with chrome using execute javascript and 'window.open' but this failed continually...

Help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I didn't find any way to hide the toolbar in Chrome, but try something like these scripts:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    open location "http://example.com"
    tell window 1 to enter presentation mode
end tell
```

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell (make new window)
        set URL of active tab to "http://example.com"
        set bounds to {0, 22, 1200, 900}
    end tell
    activate
end tell
```

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:"http://example.com"}
    tell window 1
        set bounds to {0, 22, 1200, 900}
    end tell
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    tell menu "View" of menu bar 1
        if exists menu item "Hide Toolbar" then click menu item "Hide Toolbar"
        if exists menu item "Hide Status Bar" then click menu item "Hide Status Bar"
        if exists menu item "Hide Tab Bar" then click menu item "Hide Tab Bar"
        if exists menu item "Hide Bookmarks Bar" then click menu item "Hide Bookmarks Bar"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: fwiw `tell window 1 set bounds to {0, 22, 1440, 900} end tell` will set the new window to fullscreen on a macbook air, since 1440x900 is the device's screen resolution.

Comment: great elaborate answer! thank you. i used the first example - the simple one - to run javascript on chrome. thanks!