# Is there a way to force Chrome to open in presentation mode on OSX?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, google-chrome

I would like to open on Chrome a local html file with youtube iframe embedded, automatically in presentation mode.
Is there a way to do it without using applescript or other external script, but simply adding html (or javascript) code to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, using HTML it is certainly not possible.

It would be a definite nuisance to users if every page could open in full screen at their sole discretion.

Comment: In this case it would be for a digital signage screen, so no users would interact with the the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since we cannot use HTML, the best solution I've found was to use [applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948093/applescript-to-launch-chrome-with-specifics):

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
open location "file:///path/to/file"
tell window 1 to enter presentation mode
end tell
```

An alternative and interesting solution is to create a [kiosk app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled).